# Why isn't this simple Perl push/pop program working?

Tags: perl

I'm reading the Llama ([Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520106/)) book, and working on the exercises. And for this exercise:

> Write a program that reads a list of strings on separate lines until end-of-input and prints out the list in reverse order. [. . .]

Well, I already figured out a simpler approach (I remembered you could use `reverse` on arrays... Perl is so... awesome so far), but I am wondering why this one isn't working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;

chomp(@strings = <STDIN>);

foreach (@strings){
    push @revstrings, $_;
}

while($i++ <= scalar @revstrings){
    say pop @revstrings;
}
```

It goes like this:

> $ ./first
>   **one
>
>   two
>
>   three**
>   *[^D]*
>   three
>   two
>   $

the output is the same if I change the `<=` in the while loop to just `<`.

Comment: If I may suggest, do yourself a favor and start using 

    use strict;
    use warnings;

in all your programs from the beginning. This will format your mind to good practices :)

Comment: true, but I'm loving how permissive perl is. It just lets you do whatever you want

Comment: And many things you don't want but you did by accident...

Comment: At this point in Learning Perl we haven't talked about strict yet because we haven't introduced lexical variables. We get people moving quickly without bogging them down in concepts. For short programs where you have only a couple of variables and can see the whole thing on the screen, it's not such a big deal.

Comment: One thing to think about while doing the Llama exercises: if you think you are doing a lot of work, you are. Most of the exercises at the beginning are designed for you to use a single feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll never get past halfway... Each time through that last iteration, you'd get:

- `$i++` means that `$i` will increase by one;
- `pop @revstrings` will mean that `scalar @revstrings` will decrease by one.

They'll meet in the middle, when `$i++` just exceeds half the original `@revstrings` length.

Actually, the `$i++` is unnecessary, since `scalar @revstrings` will be zero when the array is empty, so you just need:

```
while(scalar @revstrings){
    say pop @revstrings;
}
```

Comment: No need for the 'scalar' either.  The while evaluates the conditional in boolean (scalar) context.  So while( @revstrings ) { ... } will do the trick.

Comment: `*smacks forehead*`. for some reason I assumed @revstrings would get evaluated only once. Haha, that was a stupid mistake--I had the same problem before with a different structure (I forget what), so I thought I would just use $i++ so that it was just an unrelated count. If I stored the length of @revstrings in a variable and then used that in the loop, I guess it would have worked. Thanks though

Comment: You don't need the second array either: `say pop @strings while (@strings);`

Comment: @Telemachus: Damnit, you're right; foreach (@strings){
    push @revstrings, $_;
}
 is equivalent to @revstrings = @strings;

Comment: @Stobor - As of a few days ago, you can use backticks to produce code in comments (just as in a post). I don't think it always worked, but it does now. I keep meaning to check if the format rules for comments are documented anywhere, but I haven't yet.

Comment: I think it doesn't always work. I just tried it (posted my comment three times!). I wonder if there's some magic needed. ``backticks format $variables in perl <nicely>``

Comment: @Telemachus: Damnit, you're right; `` foreach (@strings){ push @revstrings, $_; } `` is equivalent to ``@revstrings = @strings; ``

Comment: Okay, I swear it wasn't doing that before. And now it only requires 1 backtick? :-S /me is confused.

Comment: Hasn't it always required one backtick?
And damn! I figured, push them on a stack and pop them off in reverse order... I guess I should have thought about this one a little harder before asking :)

Comment: I've always done two backticks, but maybe that wasn't necessary. As for the stack, Perl arrays are already built to handle all that for you. But if you're used to another language, it's natural to expect to have to do it yourself. I'm learning C now (Perl was my first language), and I'm having the reverse problem. I keep wanting there to be a built-in way for me to do things.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Short answer is "Because your loop condition is wrong." more verbose "scalar @revstrings is evaluated each iteration".

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    push @lines, $_
}

while(@lines){
    print pop @lines;
}
```

less typing

```
@lines = <STDIN>;

while(@lines){
    print pop @lines;
}
```

lesser typing

```
@lines = <STDIN>;
print reverse @lines;
```

lesser typing

```
print reverse <>;
```

but far best solution is

```
exec("tac");
```

Comment: It's not the best solution if your goal is _to learn Perl_. Not to mention that `tac` isn't present on all systems. I.e., the solution isn't portable.

Comment: What happened to `print reverse <STDIN>`?

Comment: Ok, I got curious: `tac` is mentioned in the question and the answer is `print reverse <>`. But, again, if he's trying to learn Perl, he also needs to know why his answer _didn't_ work. (_Learning Perl_ chapter 5 if you're playing along at home.)

Comment: OK, so short answer is "Because your loop condition is wrong." more verbose "scalar @revstrings is evaluated each iteration".

Comment: `sub tac { tac() if defined(my $line=<>); print $line } tac`

Comment: "`print reverse <>`" Oh wait, ... we're not going for Perl-golf.